# android paypal no peer certificate error

Tags: android, paypal, ssl-certificate, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

Paypal integration doesn't work.It shows `No peer certificate` and also shows `request failed with server response:null` and `SERVER_COMMUNICATION_ERROR`.Even I have added SSLSocketFactory to rectify https.I think SSLSocketFactory will not need.Because the issues coming from android sdk.

I had integrate paypal many times.all of them show's this error.

I have doubt on android paypal sdk.

Is it working fine now? Or Is the problem in my side?

Comment: What you want's to develop with paypal sdk using sandbox? Please reply i will try to help on that.